# WPF Deployment Error

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, setup-deployment

I have written a small WPF Application that uses SQL Server Express at the back end.  I have created a set up and deployment project for the application using Install Shield

I have deployed this just onto a Laptop which has the database on it as well.  This was working beautifully until just recently.

The changes are that previously I was using Visual Studio 2012 and Install Shield 2010 and then I upgraded to V.S 2013 and Install Shield 2015

Since doing that and then deploying the application I get the following:-

The login form for the application still loads correctly but after attempting to log in I get the standard Windows  has stopped working dialogue box

The weird thing is if I reinstall an old setup (created with VS2012 and I.S 2010) it actually runs correctly

The old setup program and the new setup program are the same

The only thing I get from event viewer is a System.IO.FileNotFound exception although no real indicators as to what or where

Could something have become corrupt on the laptop? It seems very odd to me that I can reinstall the old setup and it works fine but the new one doesn't

I have the following Exception handlers in my application but none of them fire

```
 void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)

 void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)

 void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)

 void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)

 void WinFormApplication_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
```

Can anyone please give me any suggestions?

Here is the event viewer error

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          26/08/2015 7:44:55 PM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Name
Description:
Application: ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.MainWindow..ctor()
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.App.Main()
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-26T09:44:55.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2502</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Name</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.MainWindow..ctor()
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ACS.SampleReceiptRegister.UI.App.Main()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: you're missing a dll.

Comment: Show us the error from the application event log.

Comment: Check whether you have VC++ 2013 redistributable installed on your laptop

Comment: The 2013 redistributable was not there but installing it didn't help.  I no longer get the Windows has stopped working pop up but just nothing after attempting to log in

Comment: Have added the event log

Comment: Add a side note I just installed Visual Studio 2013 on the laptop I was referring to and then ran the installed program exe and it ran successfully so obviously the visual studio install is adding dll/s that are needed but how to find those out?

Comment: repair/update your .NET framework installation